# uwsgi Failed to start uWSGI Emperor service nginx centos

Tags: nginx, centos, uwsgi

i am trying to set up the nginx on centos 7 machine to run web2py app using python 2.7.18 version.

when trying to star the uwsgi i am getting the
Failed to start uWSGI Emperor service.

My ini and other files are

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8080
#plugin =python27
#pythonpath = /home/woshi/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
gid = nginx
#chmod-socket = 664
chdir = /opt/web2py
module = wsgihandler:application

master = true
processes = 5

uid = woshi
socket = /run/uwsgi/web2py.sock
chown-socket = woshi:nginx
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

uwsgi.servcie file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After = syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown woshi:nginx /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --logto /var/log/emperor.log
#ExecStart=/home/woshi/myenv/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --logto /var/log/emperor.log
#ExecStart=/home/woshi/myenv/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/woshi/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web2py.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
#ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
ExecStart=/home/woshi/myenv/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

I am loosing my mind with this.

Any suggestions